# What does this constructor do?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-arguments

Can you explain these lines?

```cpp
class HasPtr {
public:
    HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string())://this line
    ps(new std::string(s)), i(0) { } //and this

    HasPtr(const HasPtr &p):
    ps(new std::string(*p.ps)), i(p.i) { }

    HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr &);

    ~HasPtr() { delete ps; }

private:
    std::string *ps;
    int  i;
};
```

This topic in book is about classes that act like values.

Comment: this should answer at least half of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Exactly this half of question I know)

Comment: IMO this is rubbish design, it should have `HasPtr()` and `HasPtr(const std::string&)` , the original version is slightly harder to read and slightly less efficient for no apparent reason

Answer (score 3):

In this declaration of a constructor

```
HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string())://this line
ps(new std::string(s)), i(0) { }
```

there is used the default argument `std::string()` and the mem-initializer list

```
ps(new std::string(s)), i(0)
```

that is executed before the control will be passed to the constructor body. As there is nothing to do in the body the body of the constructor is empty.

So you can call the constructor without an argument like

```
HasPtr obj;
```

in this case an empty string created like `string()` will be used as an argument.

Comment: "mem-initializer" is "member-initializer"?

Comment: @Konstantin It is a C+ construction used to initialize members of a class.

Comment: The term is actually _ctor-initializer_.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica From the C++ Standard ctor-initializer:
: mem-initializer-list :)

Comment: _mem-initializer-list_ is part of _ctor-initializer_ yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

`const std::string &s` is a reference to a const instance of `std::string`.

`= std::string()` is a default value. `xyz()` is a syntax for a [*value-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) instance of `xyz`.

So when `HasPtr` is instantiated without an argument (e.g. `HasPtr()`), the `HasPtr(s)` constructor will be invoked with `s` bound to a *temporary* blank `std::string` instance (which lives until the end of the full-expression, usually the first `;`).

Then `ps` will be initialized with `new std::string(s)`, making a copy of `s` on the heap and storing a pointer to it in `ps`.

If `HasPtr` is invoked with an actual argument, the `= std::string()` part will not execute.